# Api Gateway change default error response format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

When I send request with wrong `x-api-key`, I get default response as

```
{
  "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

I can modify error response from lambda if it hits my lambda function. But in this case aws sends default error response.

I have different error format for my endpoint

```
{
  type:"error",
  "message":"...",
  "status":"...",
  "code":403,
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to change to above format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new feature within API gateway where you can define default responses for various errors.

[image]

Documention for this feature is over here:

[API Gateway Responses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/customize-gateway-responses.html)

Comment: Gr8, till yesterday, this was not available, Thanks.